# C Static linking and dynamic linking

Tags: c, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Am working on a project that requires us to statically link a file and also dynamically link pthread_create and pthread_join in a C program.

I have found resources on the static linking but i cant seem to find anything on dynamic linking that that consists of just linking the certain parts of pthread.

would really appreciate any insight or resourcse

Comment: If i'm not wrong, you don't link functions, you link libraries. However, I'm interested in seeing other responses, too.

Comment: You forgot to mention your specific problem.

Comment: What's wrong with `-lpthread`? Why do you want to link specific functions?

Comment: You should show how you statically link the file that must be statically linked.  Normally, `pthread_create()` et al are only provided in a shared library, so you don't get an option to statically link.  However, this is platform-specific.  You should identify the platform and the compiler/linker toolchain you're using too.

Comment: Do you want to link only specific parts of dynamic library just to reduce size of executable (thats what I am assuming you are trying to achieve)?

Comment: Are you looking for dynamically linking functions ? if so, function pointers may help.

Comment: Stackoverflow.com is not a coding service.  Please post what you have tried and the results.  Be sure to post your compile and link statements.